# pull data from page without database

Tags: php

I am making a php site without using a database. I add the header and footer to the page with the include function.

How can I dynamically create meta tags by pulling information from inside the page.

```
<?php include "inc/head.php" ?>


<main>

 <article>

   <h1>Page Name</h1>

    <div>Post Body</div>
 
 </article>

</main>

<?php include "inc/footer.php" ?>
```

Comment: Any variables you want to access in the header, you would have to assign _before_ that include already.

Comment: you can use javascript for that if the data is required to be loaded on any event or on document load from page to header. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events

Comment: It's unclear...are you saying you want to parse the static HTML of your own pages, to extract certain information in order to generate meta tags? I'd suggest using a database would be a lot simpler in the long run. In fact a ready-made CMS would probably be more suitable than making your own site, if all you've got is a load of static / semi-static pages.

Comment: problem answered, thank you all for your interest, i'm new to php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is: first, define your php variables; then use them when needed. for example

in the `"inc/head.php"`file define the variables so you can access them later like

```
$page_name = 'The Page Name';
```

so now you can set your `h1` context like

```
<h1><?php echo $page_name; ?></h1>
```

Comment: thank you, my mistake didn't happen because I added the variable at the bottom